# Is there a way to determine when a number of this form is prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $n \in \mathbb N$, then is there a way to tell when $$2*n^2-1$$ is prime or $$8*n^2-1$$ is prime?

Comment: Possible collision with https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/403519/primality-of-the-numbers-in-the-form-of-2n2-1

Comment: "A way to tell"?  Yes, of course, just use one of the standard primality tests.  I doubt that there's any known specialized test just for numbers of one of these forms that is better than the standard ones.